# Caching php file and return the cached html file

Tags: php, performance

I have a really large mysql table, therefore I'm trying to chache the entire php file and return the cached html file.

I used this one [Caching Dynamic PHP pages easily](http://papermashup.com/caching-dynamic-php-pages-easily/) and it works great, but when the time has come for writing the new html file, it takes really long time to load...Where do I need to modify it...

**Php Code:**

```
$cachefile = 'cache.html';
$cachetime = 4 * 60;
// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
include($cachefile);
echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
exit;
}
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer

/* Heres where you put your page content */

// Cache the contents to a file
$cached = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking of HTML table, such caching will not speed up loading time.
It takes browser too much time to render a large table, not PHP to generate it.

So, to make things faster you have to reduce table size or implement some sort of pagination or dynamical loading.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without dynamical loading.

Comment: I'm using not a html table. I use the xampp packet with mysql